# Ubuntu 14.04 and Xmanager problem

Tags: networking, system-installation

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and when trying to connect by Xmanager 4 i got an error message

(gnome-session:8503): CRITICAL : We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....